# Move file to different destination based on conditions

Tags: ssis

> I need to move files from one folder to another folder. But before moving that particular file
>    i need to check the status of corresponding file from a table. If status is suspend then move the
>    file to suspend Folder and if it is exception then move to exception folder.

For this i am using Foreach file enumerator 
and have defined source and destination variables.

My concern is how can i move the files based on conditions.

Answer (score 0):

- Set up the connection manager as normal
- In the properties, you'll see a *Expressions* setting, set the connection string to a variable.
- Pass this variable as a **read-write** variable to a *Script Task*, inside the task you can set the variable value based on your logic
- The next step will be to move the file based on the variable value.

To set variables for Task manager...

[image]

```
public void Main()
  {
    // RO: User::varFullPath
    // RW: User::varNewPath
    var fullPath = Dts.Variables["User::varFullPath"].Value;
    var placeToStoreFile = GetNewLocation();//assume method for logic.

    Dts.Variables["User::varNewPath"].Value = placeToStoreFile.ToString();

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
 }
```

There's a small example here of how to read/write from/to variables.